# Как типизировать useForm в React hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, form

Как типизировать useForm в React hook form?

```
const { register, control } = useForm<any>({ defaultValues });
const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({ control, name: 'rulesList'});
```

Comment: Вроде же в доках написано как https://react-hook-form.com/ts/